# Cannot find table in Ruby Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-migrations, seeding

I'm trying to seed a Ruby SQLite3 database with the following commands.

```
SubmissionPool.create(
[ { submission_pool_id: "5769bdf9-ac24-4b4c-bc35-6062de526285", submission_pool_description: "images", created_at: Time.new , updated_at: Time.new  }
])

Submission.create(
[ { submission_ID: "ff336040-d5e7-4c80-a0b8-53d2204bd027", submission_title: "TestSubmission",  submission_description: "TestSubmission",
  submission_file: "http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg", created_by: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", created_at: Time.new , updated_at: Time.new  }
])
```

And it keeps giving me the error that table Submissions is not found. So far I've been creating the models with the `rails generate model` command and it has all worked out.

I tried

- Dropping the table and recreating it.
- Deleting the entire database and re migrating it.
- Tried various different caps letters (i know stupid but hey)

Now I've read somewhere that sqlite 3 isn't that good with plurals in the table name. Could any of you give me a pointer in the right direction. I'll attach my migration code and model code below.

submission.rb

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateSubmissions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :submission, :id => false do |t|
      t.uuid :submission_ID, :primary_key => true, null: false
      t.string :submission_title, null: false
      t.text :submission_description, null: false
      t.string :submission_file, null: false
      t.datetime :created_on, null: false
      t.uuid :created_by, null: false

       t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what do your db/schema.rb say?  Does it includes submissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you create table `submission`:

```
create_table :submission, :id => false do |t|
  ...
end
```

Your error is caused by this name. Rails expects `Submission` model's table to be `submissions`.

You can still use this name, but it should be explicitly be declared in `Submission` model:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name :submission
end
```